# After scaling an image with the help of CSS3's `scale` property, how to get the actual width/height of the image?

Tags: jquery

After scaling an image with the help of CSS3's `scale` property, how to get the actual width/height of the image?

Answer (score 1):

```
scale = 1.4;
$('#image').css('transform', 'scale('+scale+')');
var actual_height = $('#image').height() * scale;
```